# What is the Exchange Server endpoint for Outlook.com (for setup with third party email app)?

Tags: outlook.com

It used to be `eas.outlook.com` but that doesn't seem to work anymore. The docs online (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-email-in-android-email-app-71147974-7aca-491b-978a-ab15e360434c) still say that it is, but that endpoint just returns a 401 Unauthorized for around 19 out of 20 requests (and will inexplicably goes through seemingly randomly).

I'm trying to set up my Outlook.com account to work with a third party email app. If I just spam "retry" when it says unauthorized, after a few dozen retries, it magically works. If I remove the account and try to add it again, the same dance occurs. I've tested two separate third-party email apps and also tried setting up the account in Desktop Outlook as a manual Exchange account, and similar behavior is visible in all.

Comment: Outlook.com is the rebrand of Hotmail. That support article is for Exchange and Microsoft 365 which don't have anything to do with Outlook.com. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to do. Maybe this is what you want:  [Add Outlook.com to another mail app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-your-outlook-com-account-to-another-mail-app-or-smart-device-73f3b178-0009-41ae-aab1-87b80fa94970).

Comment: @Blindspots Hi, thanks for responding. I believe my question is clear. I am trying to get the full capabilites of Exchange ActiveSync from my consumer Outlook.com account in a third party email and calendar app. The link I posted has been the correct instructions for the past ten years, and even explicitly has sections for "Outlook.com users" and  shows a hotmail.com email in its screenshots. The alternative documentation you linked only allows for basic SMTP mail, which does not support push notifications nor the syncing of calendars and contacts.

Comment: This may be related to the change to "modern authentication" that took place with MS Exchange products. 
 You might want to look into that. May be related to [Where to find create App Password for Microsoft 365 Basic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171214/)